# Iterating over elements of environment variable in PuTTY script file

Tags: mysql, batch-file, putty

I created a bat file where I asked it to load a putty session and passed another bat file using `-m` to execute all the commands necessary. In the second bat file, I have some repeated `mysql` commands to be executed. So I created a `for` loop, and wanted to pass the list of DB names as parameters to it, *(which should be given along with the file I am asking to execute in the first bat file)*. I am not able to pass the list of DB names inside the file name using `%` symbol.

What is the solution for this.

```
SET file=%1
SET DB=%2

Putty.exe -load xyz -m %file% %DB% -t
```

This is my first bat file, I want to pass the DB name as list along with file. Can someone please help me achieve this?

---

I have some MySQL commands that are repeated for different DB's. Can I achieve that using for loop inside a bat file?

```
FOR %%q IN (%DB%) DO mysql -h xyzdb -e 'drop database %%q;'
```

This is giving a syntax error, can someone suggest where I went wrong?

Comment: It seems that you need in `FOR /F`. In current state your "DB names" are interpreted as filenames list.

Answer (score 0):

The script file that you pass to `putty` is not a batch file. It's a list of commands for *remote shell*. So:

- You have to use remote shell constructs and commands, not batch file commands.
- You cannot refer to local environment variables.

But you can generate the file using the batch file

```
FOR %%q IN (%DB%) DO echo mysql -h xyzdb -e 'drop database %%q;' > script.txt
Putty.exe -load xyz -m script.txt
```

Also, for automation, you should use `plink`, not `putty`.

---

*I'm not sure what you wanted to achieve by `%DB%` in the `putty` commandline.*